# What am I doing wrong with this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM bd2_zbiorcza
WHERE
  NOT (imie like '%a')
  AND plec = 'K';
```

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong with this query?

I want rows where `imie` does NOT end with 'a'.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and format as text rather than an image. Include the query, sample data, expected output, and any errors that occur. It'd also be beneficial to tag your question with the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with sample data and expected output  you screen shot is not even readable.

Comment: One assumes that `plek = 'K'` is related to whether or not someone is a "woman".

Comment: `column NOT LIKE '...'`

Answer (score 2):

Your query should work

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( imie, plek ) AS
SELECT 'aaa', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bbb', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cba', 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ddd', 'K' FROM DUAL;
```

**Queries**

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
WHERE  NOT( imie LIKE '%a' ) AND plek = 'K'
```

or, without the brackets:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
WHERE  NOT imie LIKE '%a' AND plek = 'K'
```

or, using `NOT LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
WHERE  imie NOT LIKE '%a' AND plek = 'K'
```

**Output**:

They all output:

> ```
> IMIE | PLEK
> :--- | :---
> bbb  | K   
> ddd  | K
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=139888639f7c04953b775e439e100b6d)*

---

What could be wrong:

1. You could have an `a` with accents (that aren't obvious as you've posted an image rather than text).
2. You could have a white-space character after the text. For exmaple: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2f03f75681797faea6f1306f0a72f942).
3. You could be storing the data in a fixed-sized `CHAR` column (that has been right-padded with spaces) rather than a variable-sized `VARCHAR2` column. For example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d0311fc73d6375b8f656ffe8a09fbb5).

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bd2_zbiorcza
WHERE
  not regexp_like(lower(imei), '.+a$')
  AND plec = 'K';
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are invisible characters behind the text.  F.e. spaces, tabs, linebreaks, …

Most of the time it's just spaces.
But you can trim those trailing spaces off when filtering them with a NOT LIKE.

For example by using the [RTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php) function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM bd2_zbiorcza
WHERE RTRIM(imie) NOT LIKE '%a'
  AND plec = 'K';
```

And if it's not just spaces, perhaps use a regex.

```
SELECT *
FROM bd2_zbiorcza
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(imie, 'a\s*$')
  AND plec = 'K';
```